# Passage time of a Brownian motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $X=\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a weak solution of
$$
dX_t = \mu(t,X)\,dt+\sigma(t,X)\,dW_t
$$
where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are measurable and W is a Brownian motion. [In this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00780-008-0087-3) it is said that
$$
\inf\{t>0;X_t>X_0\} = \inf\{t>0;X_t<X_0\} =\inf\{t>0;X_t=X_0\}=0,~~a.s.  
$$
To verify this, the reader is ask to look at the book by Karatzas and Shreve at 2.7.18. Here, however, I found only the statement of the following problem:

[image]

which does not help me much. I am therefore looking for a more didactic reference and any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Hint: Can you find an equivalent measure under which $X_t$ is a Brownian motion?

Comment: @user6247850 yes, it is enough to take intrinsic time sampling, but suppose that mu = 0 and sigma = 1, still I do not see how 7.18 implies the equation.